# Google Analytics Real-time + historical data

Tags: google-analytics, real-time, reporting

I work for a non-profit that needs to see how our fundraising efforts are going in 'real-time'.

We look at results in blocks of about a half hour - so we need to report on how we finished the last 24 hours or so and also where we're at in the current half-hour. We're accomplishing this through google analytics, as we have multiple fundraising streams all pointing to a common GA account.

I have tried using datastudio to report against the GA API, but that connector does not seem to refresh at a reliable rate - someitmes it'll pull fresh data within a minute, sometimes it can take twenty minutes to report on recent transactions. I believe the 'real-time' API could be used to get fresher GA data, but as far as I can tell, that will only report 'live' data, and not prior/historical data (say from four hours ago). Does anyone know what API I could use if any to pull all data historical through current datetime?

I apologize if this request is vague, but I'm just looking for a conceptual approach at this point to get the freshest data - preferably in one fell swoop (API call). There is more complexity post-data intake (I have to then compare it to goals we've set for each half-hour, amongst other nuances to the transacitons themselves), so i wanted to start with this fundamental piece/question.

Thanks!

Comment: i'd really appreciate anyone's thoughts on this - how can i get the most current e-commerce data along with prior period (not 'live' but an hour ago) in one api call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the context provided, I believe that the API solution would not be feasible. Among other reasons:

- The real time API only offers a limited amount of dimensions and metrics. For example, e-commerce data is not available.

  - https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/
  - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets
- The Standard intraday processing SLA for the Core Reporting API is < 24 hours for standard properties. The processing occurs on a best effort basis. Meaning that an hourly availability can occur from time to time but can not be guaranteed.

  - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7084038?hl=en

As an alternative approach to the API solution, you could consider the use of an App + Web property which would allow you to stream event data in real time to BigQuery. However, this solution has some cost implications and would introduce you to a new tracking paradigm.

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/app-web/tag-guide
- https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en
- https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/getting-started-with-google-analytics-app-web/

Comment: Thanks prvvdrs. I will have to figure out a non Google solution I think. I really appreciate your detailed reply to my questions and the links you provided.

Comment: A quick and free solution is now4real.com (full disclosure: I am the founder). It reports the historical series of concurrent visitors. You can easily see and export it from the Dashboard.